# Why does "invalid number of parameters" come up in this .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have made this code and it doesn't seem to work anymore because of invalid number of parameters:

```
xcopy C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world "C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup-%date:/=-%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2% /s /e /i
```

Comment: You are missing double quotes. There is ony one

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
xcopy /s /e /i "C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world\*.*" "C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup-%date:/=-%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%"
```

Comment: The switches can be at the beginning or the end.  It is the double quotes that are important - and `*.*` is added assuming that `world` is a folder, to give it a filespec to copy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use that command in a git hook (could be, since it isn't specified in the question), a solution could be to remove some spaces, like this:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\t\Desktop\survival\world\*.*" "C:\Users\t\Desktop\backups\survival\Backup"/s/e/i
```

and no, I don't know why.

If you have spaces in the path, you could put the xcopy command in a `somecommand.cmd` file and in the git hook call `cmd.exe /c "C:\path\to\cmdfile\copypdf.cmd"`

Comment: I'm confused, who said anything about git?

Comment: @zack6849 I did, who knows where the OP wants to apply the batch file. In any case, I put it here to hopefully help future people who come upon this issue and I provide a possible solution.

Comment: Never would've guessed to lump the flags at the end like that.  Xcopy worked on the command line but failed in a batch file and this style fixed it.  Upvote for you.